# Finding gradient of a $x^Tx + c$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I am very familiar with calculating gradients for single and multi-variable functions, as a vector containing partial derivatives.

However, when I want to calculate the gradient of a vector product, given some undefined vector, I do not understand the intuition. Say I want to calculate the gradient of $f(x) = x^Tx + c$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$

In my textbook, I have a simple table which evaluates this to $2x$. The constant of cause evaluates to zero, for any derivative by itself, but how does $x^Tx$ evaluate to $2x$?

What I am trying to understand is how intuitively to engage finding partial derivatives of a vector, without knowing its values.

I might think of $x^T$ as a vector containing multiple inputs: $[x_1,...,x_n] \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and similar for $x$ (but as a column vector), but how would I go about finding the gradient of such an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Expanding in components, we find that $$x^\top x = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 .$$

Comment: So your expanding with respect to a dot product, correct? But with this expansion we have $x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2$, and for me intuitively this is a scalar over the sum of the dot product. Would you then just consider each term as part of the vector $x$ and find the derivative directly from this? So $\sum_{n=1}^{N} 2 \cdot x_n$ or just $2 \cdot x$?

Comment: You can think of the expression as evaluating a dot product, but we can just think of the expression as a product of a row vector $x = \pmatrix{x_1 & \cdots & x_n}$ and its transpose. The ith component of the gradient $\nabla f$ is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial_x}$, or in our case, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2) = 2 x_i$. So, $\nabla (x^\top x) = 2 x$ as claimed.

Comment: Alright thanks - that clarifies it very simply. I guess I just over complicated the solution in my head, thinking I would somehow have to evaluate for partial derivatives in terms of these individual components of the vector $x$. I now see its not the case :)

Comment: You're welcome. Once you see that $x \mapsto x^\top x$ is just a function on $\Bbb R^n$, everything follows from definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to think about the derivative is
$$
\tag{1} f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x.
$$
In this example, if $\Delta x$ is small, then
\begin{align*}
f(x + \Delta x) &= x^T x + x^T \Delta x + \Delta x^T x + \underbrace{\Delta x^T \Delta x}_{\text{negligible}} \\
&\approx x^T x + x^T \Delta x + \Delta x^T x \\
&= f(x) + 2 x^T \Delta x.
\end{align*}
Comparing this with (1), we discover that
$$
f'(x) = 2 x^T.
$$
The gradient of $f$ is
$$
\nabla f(x) = f'(x)^T = 2x.
$$
So there's no need to compute partial derivatives or to think in terms of the components of $x$.

Comment: Alright that makes sense :) For me its just the intuition of computing the actual partial derivatives, that made me a bit confused in cases working with vectors, or even matrices (expanding from this).

Answer (score 0):

Just just the Leibniz-rule (using $a^Tb=b^Ta$):
$$d_p(x^Tx)=p^Tx+x^Tp=x^Tp+x^Tp=2x^Tp,$$
hence the gradient of $x^Tx$ is  $2x$.